# What are the indications of fat reducing?

Tags: weight-loss

After trying very hard and keeping diet continued i actually don't see any change after months.but what if it is there but i don't see it. Please tell me how can i personally know that my body is getting correct shape and weight (apart from simply measuring weight).

Comment: Are you tracking your actual weight on a scale? Or is it that you are losing weight, but not realizing it?

Comment: This is a very subjective question.  You need to separate your visual expectations from actual measurements.  After all, what is the "correct shape and weight"?  That's very individual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Ideal: DEXA body-fat scan

### 2nd best: Take tape measurements

Measure your:

- Waist
- Hips
- Thigh
- Calves
- Upper Arm
- Lower Arm
- Chest
- Neck

#### 3rd Best: Take photos every month and compare them once you have 6 months passed.